# `npm` and `nodejs` incompatibilities

Tags: software-installation, apt, node.js

I installed `npm` and `nodejs` today because I wanted to try [`tldr-pages`](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr).

After the obligatory `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Following a huge download of "stuff", which concluded successfully, I tried installing my objective app:

```bsh
$ npm install -g tldr
```

This was immediately followed by a **strange** warning:

> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.23.1
> npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
> npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
> npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Taken literally, the WARNING is nonsense as it says: **1)** your version of `nodejs` is not supported & should be ***upgraded***, and **2)** supported releases are only ***older*** versions!

I know nothing about `npm` and `nodejs`. Is this a problem with RPi's repo - or is this a reflection of the state of these apps? Is there a known resolution for this?

Comment: I normally get around this by using nvm

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=245989

Comment: @SteveRobillard: A bit of *helter-skelter*?   :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packaged on debian based distribution:

```
sudo apt install tldr
```

With `npm`:

Install a [supported nodejs version](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Then run:

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
sudo npm install tldr -g
```

---

> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.23.1
> npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node ...

You need to upgrade `npm`:

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

Comment: `sudo apt install tldr`... I saw that, but the reference to Haskell in `apt-cache search tldr` threw me off as I thought it was tldr ***specific to Haskell***  :)